# Break a number into factors.

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

I want to split a number in a product of factors, i am not sure how to do it.

(2^48)+1

I think it should involve either mersenne or fermat little theorem.
I have factored 48 and i have [(2^2^4)*2^3]+1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the factorization $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ for certain values of $a$ and $b$.

FYI: According to Wolfram Alpha, $2^{48}+1$ is the product of $3$ primes, so it is hard (but not impossible) to do better than the factorization I suggested.

Comment: Well, $2^{16}+1$ is a known Fermat prime.  Any good way to factor $2^{32}-2^{16}+1$?

Comment: Is there a nice way to know that $2^{48} \equiv -1 \pmod{193}$? We do know that $(2^{48})^4 = 2^{192} \equiv 1 \pmod{193}$ since $193$ is prime.